# How do I login to Ubuntu Core?

Tags: login, password, ubuntu-core

I just configured Ubuntu Core on my Raspberry Pi 3 and now it is now asking for a user name and password in the terminal (I think). It says:

```
Ubuntu Core 16 on <my ip address> (ttyl)
localhost login:
Password:
```

I'm not sure whether these fields are for your Ubuntu account username and password or email and password or whatever. I've tried my Ubuntu account username and password and I also tried it with my email and password. Neither worked so I tried leaving them blank which also didn't work.

Is there some default password or did I put it in earlier and if so when or where? If I knew that I might be able to remember what I put.

Comment: The username needs to be the one specified in your SSO account (the initial setup printed it out), and the password is not the Ubuntu One password but the password to unlock the SSH key uploaded to your SSO account. The login is now protected via those SSH keys, not by a password.

Comment: Take a look at step 4 [here](https://ubuntu.com/download/iot/raspberry-pi-2-3) : use "ubuntu" for the username and the password

Answer (score 5):

Ubuntu Core 16 does *not* come with a default user name and password. Ubuntu Core requires you to setup a Ubuntu SSO account with your SSH keys, which enable you access to your device. Once in, you can create your own user. Please find the relevant instructions [here](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/snappy/start/raspberry-pi-2/).

Comment: Just a heads up that the link is broken

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue at first.

If you are on a windows machine trying to use putty follow the directions here:

https://www.howtoforge.com/ssh_key_based_logins_putty

Comment: Can you please elaborate on your Answer?  Posting a URL without any instructions is not ideal. A short Step by Step would be great :)

Answer (score 1):

If your public key is correctly installed in Ubuntu Core device, when you try login, it not prompt password (with your private key in .ssh directory). So, it prompts password, your device has not correctly installed your public key.
Review the account in ubuntu.com, probally you paste the content of file of your public key in your account incorrecly

I needed four tries to login, and a lot of time to understand.

It would bi it very useful be able to upload the key.pub file

Answer (score 1):

If someone still don't know how to login to Ubuntu Core 16 for the first time, here is my solution:

1. Open PuTTY and load the session that will connect to your Raspberry Pi 3

[image: step 1]

2. Select Auth node on the left panel and Browse to the ssh private key, then hit Open button
   [image: step 2]

After that, it will ask you for login and passphrase for your private key (if you set passphrase when generate ssh key)

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question being asked.  Keep in mind that your solution requires **Windows** to work, and this is not a Windows support site.  OP hasn't said *anything* about whether Windows is at play here or not, and OP isn't even talking about remote access/SSH.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I thought that it's stakoverflow. Should I delete my  answer?

Answer (score 0):

You should have added your public ssh key into your [Ubuntu SSO account](https://login.ubuntu.com/) at [this page](https://login.ubuntu.com/ssh-keys)

Logging in requires that your ssh client has the private ssh key. There should be no password required

More details are present in [the docs](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/snappy/start/raspberry-pi-2/)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on AskUbuntu.)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the same issue by:

- First, generate a private and public key on your PC.

> ssh-keygen -t rsa -C example -b 2048

- Second, copy and save the generated public key (file.pub) on the [UbuntuOne](https://login.ubuntu.com/ssh-keys) portal.
- Third, Try to login to the device using the SSH with the private key on your pc

> ssh -i id_rsa username@xx.xx.xx.xx

Answer (score 0):

If you did not use the default `id_rsa` when creating your key then you will need to specify the key when connecting to it.

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/ubuntu-one_rsa user@ip-address
```

Answer (score -1):

Check that you're typing your username exactly as it should be (including case), by comparing it to the output of `whoami` run in a terminal.

Probably the keyboard layouts configuration is wrong fo the tty (which is a different setting than Xorg / Unity) and your password is wrong because of this.

Make sure you're typing the correct password by first typing it in the login field where you can see if it's being written as expected.

If the keymap is the case then try to rebuild it with command:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure console-setup
```

And reboot before the next try.