# ubuntu core 18 first ssh login fails on raspi 4 fails

Tags: raspberrypi

I followed the tutorial on how to install, configured the network and email-address.

I created the ssh-keys as described. 
Copied the pub-key to my account.
priv-key is in the .ssh directory.

When i try to login via ssh the prompt ask for a password instead on letting me
in.

What did I do wrong?

Hardware raspi 4 with 4 gig ram and 64gig sd card

Software ubuntu core as provided by raspberry imager

Comment: isn't SSH disabled by default on the base image?  I could've swore I had to manually add a file to the sd card last time I set that up.  Yup https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/ssh/

Comment: tried that, didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu Core requires BOTH a local keyboard/display (or [serial console](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1245266/connect-to-raspberry-pi-4-with-ubuntu-core-18-via-serial-cable)) AND a working network connection during it's first boot. It will keep repeating the first boot until both are satisfied.

- The local connection is needed so you can input your Ubuntu One username to the Ubuntu Core system.
- The network connection is needed so the Ubuntu Core system can download your SSH Key from Ubuntu One.

Then the Ubuntu Core system will reboot to apply the new settings. During reboot, you can disconnect the local keyboard/monitor.

If you leave the local display/console attached, you will see that subsequent boots will merely display the Ubuntu Core system's IP address; a convenience so you can connect using ssh. You won't be able to login using the local console by default (you can enable that feature).

One super-easy way to learn about Ubuntu Core first boot is to [try it in a disposable KVM Virtual Machine](https://ubuntu.com/download/kvm).

Tutorial: [How to install Ubuntu Core on Raspberry Pi](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-install-ubuntu-core-on-raspberry-pi)

Comment: thanks for the quick answer. I did it by the book. The machine connects to the account and I can connect via ssh to the machine. It just doesn't use the ssh keys provided.